# Google Tag Manager Form Submission and form Click

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

In my website I have a link that direct user to form submission page.I want to track how many user have clicked the link and also have click the submit button after filling the  form 
I want do the implementation using Google tag manager

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 virtual pageviews and one goal with a funnel. One pageview will be for link click and other will be for form submition.

Comment: hey mrbubu the problem is that when user submit the form page url changes due to which virtual page is not working. Do you have any other idea that can work

Comment: As I understand, you want to track 2 steps of a user. Goals with funnels is a good way to do that. But you can use funnels only with pageviews. You can use any URL with virtual pageview and it doesn't matter if URL of current page is changing.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a Form Click Listener (see https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/3415369?hl=en).  Make sure the "Wait for Tags" option is selected when you're setting up the listener.  Also make sure it sends an "event", not a "virtual pageview".

It's better to use an event rather than a virtual pageview in this case.  Using a virtual pageview will inflate your pageview stats, causing them to be a lot higher than they should be.  Virtual pageviews should be used in situations where something happens that should be counted as a pageview but the page doesn't actually change - for example: content loading in a page whose URL doesn't change).

I hope this helps.  Please comment if you need clarification.

Comment: Hi Jdmlouis can u pls help me on below requirement also 
There is slight change in the requirement  
here i  want to track no. of user and also below scenario I have two links on my homepage ( Get update  & stay connect ) which on click direct user/visitor to a form which user/visitor fills and get registered
I have two scenario to track :
1) I want to track how many anonymous user have clicked "Get update" link and got registered  
2) I want to track how many anonymous user have clicked on "stay connect"  link and got registered
need to implement using GTMV2 .need to deliver report urgently

Comment: You'd need to apply some custom dimensions to your pages. When someone clicks on the "get update" or "stay connected" links, you'll update a custom dimension value corresponding to each of those items. Unfortunately, you won't be able to get that data in time for your report, as when you apply custom dimensions, they only work for data that's collected after you've set them up.  Sorry for the bad news.